# link button is not visible in Gridview after binding using jquery in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

i am binding the gridview using jquery and try to add link button on 1st column but link button is not visible/Added. It showing blank column

here is my code
 aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TM " HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="150px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Test" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="150px" DataField="UserId" HeaderText="User Name"
                                    ItemStyle-CssClass="ContactName" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Team" HeaderText="Team" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Benutzergruppe" HeaderText="Benutzergruppe" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Freigabe" HeaderText="Freigabe" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

and java script code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            GetCustomers(1);
        });
        $("[id*=txtSearch]").live("keyup", function () {
            GetCustomers(parseInt(1));
        });
        $(".Pager .page").live("click", function () {
            GetCustomers(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
        });
        function SearchTerm() {
            return jQuery.trim($("[id*=txtSearch]").val());
        };
        function GetCustomers(pageIndex) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetCustomers",
                data: '{searchTerm: "' + SearchTerm() + '", pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        var row;
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var customers = xml.find("Customers");
            if (row == null) {
                row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            }
            $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr").not($("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:first-child")).remove();
            if (customers.length > 0) {
                $.each(customers, function () {
                    var customer = $(this);
                    $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("TM").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("UserId").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("Team").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("Benutzergruppe").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(4).html($(this).find("Freigabe").text());
                    $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(row);
                    row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                });
                var pager = xml.find("Pager");
                $(".Pager").ASPSnippets_Pager({
                    ActiveCssClass: "current",
                    PagerCssClass: "pager",
                    PageIndex: parseInt(pager.find("PageIndex").text()),
                    PageSize: parseInt(pager.find("PageSize").text()),
                    RecordCount: parseInt(pager.find("RecordCount").text())
                });

                $(".ContactName").each(function () {
                    var searchPattern = new RegExp('(' + SearchTerm() + ')', 'ig');
                    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(searchPattern, "<span class = 'highlight'>" + SearchTerm() + "</span>"));
                });
            } else {
                var empty_row = row.clone(true);
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).attr("colspan", $("td", row).length);
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).attr("align", "center");
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).html("No records found for the search criteria.");
                $("td", empty_row).not($("td:first-child", empty_row)).remove();
                $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(empty_row);
            }
        };
    </script>
```